# how can I store all of the database records from a username(from registration) but it is based on the user input?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

Here is my log in page code. What I want to do is when the user inputs his/her username, it will then get all of the database records "based on that username input" of the customer and store it in a single session.

```
protected void btn_Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = 'PAULO'; Initial Catalog=ShoppingCartDB;Integrated Security =True");
    conn.Open();
    string checkuser = "select count(*) from UserData where Username = '" + txtUser.Text + "'";
    SqlCommand scm = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
    int temp = Convert.ToInt32(scm.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
    conn.Close();
    if (temp == 1)
    {
        conn.Open();
        string checkPassword = "select Password from UserData where Username ='" + txtUser.Text + "'";
        SqlCommand passCom = new SqlCommand(checkPassword, conn);
        string password = passCom.ExecuteScalar().ToString().Replace(" ", "");
        if (password == txtPassword.Text)
        {
            Session["Username"] = txtUser.Text;
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Record saved successfully')</script>");
            Response.Redirect("OrderNow.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            lblcrederror.Text = ("Credentials dont match");
        }

    }
    else
    {
        lblcrederror.Text = ("Credentials dont match");
    }
}
```

I have set the `Session["Username"]` to the user input(`txtUser.text`), but what I want to do is to get all of the database records on that username that the customer will enter.

Afterwards, I am planning to call on that specific database record and bind it to the order .aspx page. I have tried this code below but its only showing me the `Session["Username"]`, since I have called it on the login page.

```
txtCustomerName.Text = Session["Username"].ToString();
txtCustomerPhoneNo.Text = Session["Contact"].ToString();
txtCustomerEmailID.Text = Session["Email"].ToString();
txtCustomerAddress.Text = Session["DeliveryAddress"].ToString();
```

Comment: What is the exact issue you are facing now?

Comment: You can get the information you need after querying the database based on the username right?

Comment: im not seeing the records(contact,email,delivery address) inside the textbox on my order.aspx. page. but the username is working fine when i comment out the contact email and deliveryaddress.

Comment: You can store your complete user object to session state and fetch it's properties there. I do similar stuff by storing a hashed user id in session and retrieving relevant data with the id. On a footnote you shouldn't store plain text passwords, and also you shouldn't use user input text directly in sql queries.

Comment: so what im planning to do is that on Session["username"], i  want to store all of the records based on that username. this is in the login page.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a data structure to store the information you need.

```
    public class Person
        {
            public string Username { get; set; }
            public string Contact { get; set; }
            public string Email { get; set; }
            public string Password { get; set; }
        }
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
        "SELECT * FROM databaseTablename where username = " + txtUser.Text, conn))
        {
    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Person person = new Person();
                person.Username = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("username"));
                person.Contact = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("contact"));
                person.Email = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("email"));
                person.Password = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("password"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can then store this object in a session like so:

```
Session["username"] = person;
```

Later on, if you want to access the contents of the session, say in the `Order.aspx` page, you can do like so:

```
Person person = (Person)Session["username"];
```

Comment: what if i want to store data from the database?

Comment: You can use your query results to assign values to the properties, something like `person.Email = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("email"));`

Comment: not working for me sir. lets go back to problem sir. on my login.aspx page, i have declared Session["username"] = txtUser.Text in which is working fine when i click on the login button. i am able to see the username being inputted by the user. the main problem is i want to get other records from that username, for me to be able to bind other data to the textboxes. all codes should be on the login.aspx for the codes to be read on the next page after logging in.

Comment: you problem is quite straight-forward. a user enters a username and password from the login page, you check from the database if the combination is correct, if the combination is correct, you query additional details from the database based on the username so you get results, you store the query results in a `Person` object and then you store this `Person` object in a session, you access the contents of the session in your `Order.aspx` file.

Comment: where will i put on the code that you have provided? maybe i got the worng place for the code?

Comment: you can put it inside this block `if (password == txtPassword.Text){`, but please don't just copy the code. It's just a proof of concept, an idea on how you would be able to solve your problem.

Comment: what is the "hasrows" for? and what is the line of code where it gets the data from the database? sorry if i sound stupid.

Comment: The code where it gets data from the database? - you've used it yourself, look at your `SqlCommand`. As I said, the code above is just a proof of concept, it's just a snippet. `hasRows` - up to you to do the research, happy coding :). Here's a good example http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlcommand

Comment: i mean on the session part? where is the part of the code where it gets all of the data from database based on the username?

Comment: if you want to show data based on username. and you want to navigate to oher page, you should store the data in session and on other page you should store the session value which contains all data into object. same as @jmc mentioned in the answer. now why you want to retrieve data from database when you have that data in session

Comment: in your code, you have created only one session that is for username. and you are expecting that all other data will be shown. tho they are not stored in session

Answer (score 0):

get the records from the database. Store it in a comma separated string.

```
   SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = 'PAULO'; Initial Catalog=ShoppingCartDB;Integrated Security =True");
conn.Open();
string checkuser = "select count(*) from UserData where Username = '" + txtUser.Text + "'";
SqlCommand scm = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
SqlDataAdapter da=new SqlDataAdapter(scm); 
DataSet ds=new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
conn.Close();
string userdata="";
foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count; i++)
    {
     userdata+=","+row[i].ToString();
    }
}
userdata=userdata.TrimStart(',');
Session["username"]= userdata;
```

for getting all the records just get this string from session and split it

```
If(Session["username"]!=null)
String user=Session["username"].ToString();
string[] udat=user.Split(',');
```

you can get all data in this string array.
Im kind of new to programming so please excuse any error.

Answer (score 0):

This is for storing your all values in single session

```
 DataBaseConnection db = new DataBaseConnection();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = db.executeNonQuery("Your Query that retrieves all user's data goes here");
    if(dt.Rows.Count > 0)
     {
    List<string> lst = new List<string>();
    foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
    lst.Add(dr["Cloumn_1"].ToString());
    lst.Add(dr["Column_2"].ToString());

    .

    .

    Session["YourSessionName"] = lst;
    }
     }
```

here DataBaseConnection is class that returns connection string of database, so now you know what to do.

i hope this helps. Let me know